# Get image from HTTP POST with PHP

Tags: php, iphone, html, http, post

So I am sending an image over the internet using HTTP POST and sending it to a php script on my server. I want to be able to take that image and save it. I am doing this fine with text, but when it comes to other content, such as an image, it is error-ing saying it can not find the variable, and when I try `file_get_contents`, it does not like that either. I am sending the image from an iPhone as well, so my POST Request looks like this.

```
NSMutableData *postBody = [NSMutableData data];
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"media\"; filename=\"dummy.jpg\"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[@"Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[@"Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:imageData];
[postBody appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postRequest setHTTPBody:postBody];
```

The rest of the request is written, but I do not really feel like posting all of it.

But regardless, that is how I am sending the request, and on the php server side,

```
<?php
    echo "Some Message";
    $nameValue =  $_POST['name'];
    echo "<br/>";
    echo $nameValue;
    $otherValue =  $_POST['other'];
    echo "<br/>";
    echo $otherValue;
    file_get_contents('dummy.jpg');
    // or I tried this
    $imageData = $_POST['media'];
?>
```

I can not seem to be able to grab the image. Both attempts of getting the image failed and I do not know why. Any suggestions?

**EDIT:**

I added the print statement `print_r($_FILES)` to see what I would get and it returned the following.

```
(
    [media] => Array
        (
            [name] => dummy.jpg
            [type] => 
            [tmp_name] => 
            [error] => 1
            [size] => 0
        )
)
```

So it seems as if it is getting the image, at least the name of it, but for some reason it is not getting the actual data and is throwing some error. I imagine this is probably on the iPhone side of things if it is not sending the data and my PHP server is seeing an error. I am unsure though, anyone ever experience something like this?

**EDIT 2:**

I finally got everything working. It turns out that everything was formatted properly I was just having a file image size upload limit issue. The images I was sending were around 8MB and apparently our server can not handle that, so I simply downed the quality on the jpeg, and that issue was solved. Then there were some permissions issues, as well, nothing a little bit of `sudo chmod` can't fix. Thanks everyone for your suggestions and help, I wish I could accept more than one answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error code "1" means that the image you tried to upload is too big.
http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

Check your upload_max_filesize setting in php.ini.

I saw that your are trying to continue with $_FILES['media']['name'], but the actually uploaded file is available by the path given in $_FILES['media']['tmp_name'].

To be sure you handle your upload correctly refer to the php-docu:
http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Comment: Alright, well I got past the whole file size issue by simply reducing the quality of the image that was being uploaded, now I just need to get past the issues of file read and write permissions

Comment: ok. I saw you might need to read further on how to handle file-uploads with php. So I edited ny answer with some more information

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have successfully gotten the image onto my computer, from the iPhone, using HTTP POST methods. I was also able to move the image properly around through directories and all of that, so everything should be pretty good to go. Thanks again!

Comment: Your attached links are dead.

Answer (score 0):

First you must output the result of `file_get_contents` (1), then you need to tell the browser that you're serving up an image instead of standard HTML (2).

```
echo file_get_contents('dummy.jpg'); // 1
header("Content-Type: image/jpg");   // 2
```

I just skimmed the surface for the `header` function; you'll want to add a few more headers in a real-world case. Check out:

- [php headers](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

Comment: I tried doing something like this, but still I have not had any success. Do you know of any tutorials for this kind of stuff? I have been looking around but can not seem to be able to find anything.

Comment: The issue is that I do not have a copy of the file stored locally, it is coming over in the http post. Whenever I am trying to use these methods it seems as if it is looking for that image locally, not from the post message it received, based on the error message I am getting. 'Warning: readfile(dummy.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in [server directory] on line 11'

Comment: So... is someone passing a URL to an image via `$_GET` or are you trying to handle an upload and display the uploaded file?

Answer (score 0):

Check the $_FILES array on the PHP side and see if your image is in there...

Do `print_r($_FILES);`

Comment: Edited my question to include results of doing this. Thanks

Comment: Great, I see that the array contains the name but also contains an error of status 1 (not good) and that the size of the file is zero. I'm sure that this has lead you to the end result of fixing you issue... Happy to help out!