# Img upload on opencart

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, opencart

I`m trying to add pictures to reviews on opencart products.
I use jquery.form.js ([from here](http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js))

I get the name of the file(C:fakepath/Image.png),but I cant proceed from there.I cant figure our there exactly is this file located on the server.
Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

C:fakepath/Image.png is the path generated by browsing on windows when you are uploading the image with a input type file. You need to post the image on the server to get your image server path.

Comment: It`s in a form,which is later put into the database using a model. it is in a functon and I could get all the fields using $this->request->get('field') (each one except for the image).I cant figure out how to get this image. I used $this->request->get("image-name") ,or even $FILES[],but none of them work.

Comment: you have the image attached to the post body man, on server transform the request blob (check mime type and size) into an image what you are saving it on the server.

Comment: Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11871668/get-image-from-http-post-with-php I dont have knoleges in php